# Separate imeplementation file (cpp file) of only one class into separate files

Tags: c++, class, header

I would like to separate the long implementation of **class** (**.cpp file**) into separate files.

For instance, consider I have 10 functions inside class and implementation of all these 10 functions inside .cpp file consists around 200 lines of code.

Now, the question is how to separate all of these functions into separate files when all of them together are making a class.

This is an example by code inside header (classA.h) file:

```
Class A{

       A(); 
       ~A();  
       double add(double a1, double a2); 
       double subtract(double a1, double a2); 
       double multiply(double a1, double a2); 
       double divide(double a1, double a2); 
}
```

The corresponding .cpp file is:

```
#include "classA.h"

double A::add(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
subtract(a1, a2); // **add also calls subtract function**
} 

double A::subtract(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
} 

double A::multiply(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
} 

double A::divide(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
}
```

Now, suppose I would like to separate this .cpp file to separate files called for instance "add.cpp", ... which all of these files are implementing functions of a class.

The problem of separating these functions into separate files is that they don't know the class functions! (However, I include .h file of the class to files!)

What is your suggestions to do so?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. Each cpp file is an **independent** compilation unit (i.e., when starting to process a unit, the compiler "forgets everything it ever knew" from the previous unit).

Comment: That's what the header file and its class definition is for.

Comment: One thing to think about, if your class function definitions take up so much space that you need to separate them out, your class might be doing too much.

Comment: "don't know the class functions! " , in which way ? you get a compilation error ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no any problem to separate the functions implementation in different source files, even if they belong to the same class:

file **classA_add.cpp**:

```
#include "classA.h"

double A::add(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
subtract(a1, a2); // **add also calls subtract function**
}
```

file **classA_substract.cpp**:

```
#include "classA.h"

double A::subtract(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
}
```

file **classA_multiply.cpp**:

```
#include "classA.h"

double A::multiply(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
}
```

file **classA_divide.cpp**:

```
#include "classA.h"

double A::divide(double a1, double a2){
// around 5 lines of code
}
```

All of those .cpp files known the interface of the class because it is declarated in "classA.h".

But first, check if you do not need to break the class in different classes instead breaking the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Then, I have to check it again because I did your same way and wasn't working!

Comment: In what way it was not working? compiling error? linking error?

Comment: I was including the header file of class to the function, but it couldn't know another function which was implemented inside .cpp file of the class. Now, I'm trying to change my code to check it again.

Comment: The problem was that, I was trying to create .h file for each new .cpp file for implementing functions inside class and it couldn't know those functions inside class (My be I'm not explaining it well!), but now it is working ;)

Answer (score 1):

> the question is how to separate all of these functions into separate files when all of them together are making a class.

In exactly the same way as you (presumably) already sperate the functions of different classes into separate files:

1. Create a source file.
2. Define 0 to n functions (from 0 to m classes, or free functions).
3. Include all required headers so that the declarations/definitions depended on by the defined functions are included.
4. If all functions are defined, you're done. Otherwise jump to 1.

Member functions are in no way required to be in the same source file, and functions from different classes aren't required to be in separate source files. That is just a common convention.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you #include your .h file in each of these .cpp files and *link them all together in your Makefile* there is no problem in separate the implementation in many .cpp files.